# hot to starts selection from only on currently drag td

Tags: jquery

```
  $(document).live('mouseup', function () { flag = false; });
            $(".csstablelisttd").live('mousedown', function (e)
            {

                $(".csstdselected").removeClass("csstdselected").addClass('csstdgreen');
                //This line gets the index of the first clicked row.
                lastRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
                var rowIndex = $(this).closest("tr").index();
                var colIndex = $(e.target).closest('td').index();
                $(".csstdhighlight").removeClass("csstdhighlight");


                //$('td:nth-child(' + colIndex + ')').addClass('csstdhighlight');

                //$(this).children(":gt(" + colIndex + ")").addClass("csstdhighlight");
                $(this).children(":not(:first)").addClass("csstdhighlight");
                e.preventDefault();
                flag = true;
                return false;
            });
            document.onmousemove = function () { return false; };
            $(".csstablelisttd").live('mouseenter', function (e)
            {
                // Compares with the last and next row index.
                currentRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
                if (lastRow == currentRow || lastRow == currentRow - 1 || lastRow == currentRow + 1)
                {
                    lastRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0].rowIndex;
                } else
                    return;

                if (flag)
                {


$(this).children(":not(:first)").addClass("csstdhighlight");
                        e.preventDefault();
                        if ($(".csstdhighlight").length >= 6)
                        {
                            //alert("Time slot not more than 45 minutes.");
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
```

See in my table there are 8 coloumns and 48 rows I haev to do user can start drag only one coloumn but more than 1 rows

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jquYB/)

Comment: Not that clear : colindex is not an html element... So you want to add a class to the td ? Could you show more code (jquery + html) ? A jsfiddle, maybe ?

Comment: in above js fiddle i have to select coloumn except 1 and 2nd ...at a time only one coloumn but more than one row of that coloumn is selected not more than 6 cells of the same coloumn ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the nth-child selector:

```
$('td:nth-child(' + (colIndex + 1) + ')').addClass('foo');
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jquYB/2/) is a modification of your jsFiddle.

Comment: Which six cells?  The first six? The closest six?

Comment: Here in jS fiddle i am dragging ....handling 3 events live,mousedown and mouseenter

Comment: I don't see that in your jsfiddle or in your question.  I've answered your question as it is written.  If you want more help edit your question to describe more specifically what you are trying to do, or ask another question.

Comment: see again jsfiddle there are three events to drag on cell class is not aply afer drag  i m checking why

Comment: Like I said, your question does not match what you are trying to ask me here.  You need to edit your question with more details, or preferably ask another question that specifically describes what you are trying to do.

Comment: ur solution is corect but on drag i have to select ...in ur solution when i click on cell then whole column get selected....i have drag columns like excel sheet